# Is it "case or box of beer"?

Tags: word-choice

[image]

Normally I heard people say a case of beer more than a box but what differentiate the terms of use? Is the picture attached a case or a box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attached picture is definitely a box.

That said, there are many things we sell and buy in more or less fixed quantities. Sometimes, such a quantity just refers to (a way of) packing it, and the quantity is not easily derived.

In the case of beer, when you buy a sixpack, it is quite obvious that that contains six bottles or cans of beer.

A case, for me (but there are, no doubt, regional differences!), is not necessarily a (hard polymer) case containing usually 24 bottles of 33 cl each, but any amount of beer that is more or less the same as that case. So 4 sixpacks of 33cl cans would be equivalent to a case.

The quantity does not have to be precise, though. Your box contains 36 cans. Assuming they are 33cl cans, that would be 1,5 case of beer. In colloquial speech, it may well be referred to as "a case of beer" though.

Comment: It's a case of beer that happens to be packed in a box. (That's how I'd explain it.)

Comment: Beer nowadays are usually packed in boxes rather than a real case(plastic that you mentioned), so technically if it's something around that quantity (24x33cl) it could be called a case even if it's in a box or carton or whatever?

Comment: @user49119 Yups, you can call the quantity a case, no matter how it;s packed. "Usually" depends much on your geographical location, by the way :)